# Programmatically created UITextField hides other controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uitextfield

I've requirement to create dynamically some controllers. In the image provided here I've programmatically added an `UITextField` (name), which hides UITableView.

[image]

`UITableView` is hidden by default. When user touches the `UIButton` above it, `UITableVIew` gets appear.

My question when `UITableView` gets appear, how can I make `UITableView` top of all other controls?

Comment: bring the tableView to front of the view after adding the textfield..

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tableView];

Hope this helps

Comment: @coder284 thnx, answer resides in your comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: yourTableView];
```

Answer (score 2):

you will have to change the sequence.
Add UItextfield first

```
[self.view addSubview:yourTextField];
```

and add tableview and other views after that line of code so that they appear above it.

```
[self.view addSubview:yourTableView];
```

Comment: Oh then i suppose bringSubviewToFront will be the best option. This is the first thought I had when I saw the screenshot . :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine so please implement this one.

```
 UITextField *txtFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 300, 200, 30)];
    txtFld.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Border Style None
    [txtFld setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    [txtFld setPlaceholder:@"Name"];

    [self.view addSubview:txtFld];
```